# Обработка строк макросом в цикле до первой пустой строки, оптимизация записанного средствами Excel макроса

Tags: visual-basic

имеется следующий (записанный средствами Excel) макрос:

```
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-6
      Rows("18:18").RowHeight = 42
```

Как сделать так, чтобы макрос отрабатывал с 18 по первую пустую стоку

Answer (score 0):

Смотри, в макросе который ты выложил присутствует строка
`ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-6.`
Это маленькая прокрутка экрана вниз. Она не нужна для работы макроса. Очевидно, она добавилась в макрос случайно, поэтому я её исключу. Дальше. Чтобы строки с первой по восемнадцатую сделать высотой в 42 пункта, используй следующий код:

```
Rows("1:18").Select
Selection.RowHeight = 42
```

А вообще это проще сделать вручную)